# Data from socket factory (AutobahnJs) in controller Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, websocket, autobahn

I have socket factory with using AutobahnJs.

```
app.factory('socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    var pubsub = new ab.Session(
      'wss://site.com:62315',
      function(session) {

         pubsub.subscribe('455548878', function(topic, data) { 
                var seder = {};
                seder.data = data;
                return seder;
         });

        console.log('New Session Established');
        return session;
      },
      function(code, reason) {
        console.log('Websocket connection closed. Code: '+code+'; reason: '+reason);
      }
    );
    return {
      pubsub: pubsub
    };
  }]);
```

When socket event, i need use object seder (return seder) in controller. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a ready component like angular-autobahn. 
For example [angular-wamp](https://github.com/voryx/angular-wamp).

In the current version Autobahn.js  ignore any result of on subscription event handler.